# Question about reflection+orthogonality

Tags: orthogonality, reflection, orthogonal-matrices

One short (probably stupid) question, if anyone can unclear this to me:

Why for $α ∈ O(n)$ holds $r(α(v))= αr (v)α^{−1}$?

Here $r(v)$ is is reflection across the hyperplane consisting of all vectors orthogonal to v.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what both sides do to the vector $u = \alpha v$:

\begin{align}
r(\alpha(v))(u) 
& = r( \alpha  (v))\alpha (v)\\
& = \alpha (v) \\
&= u.\\ 
\\
\alpha r (v)\alpha^{−1}(u) 
&= \alpha r (v)\alpha^{−1}(\alpha(v)) \\
&= \alpha r (v)(v) \\
&= \alpha (v) = u 
\end{align}

Now suppose that $w$ is orthogonal to $\alpha(v)$. Then we have that $\alpha^{-1}(w)$ is orthogonal to $v$, because $\alpha$ preserves inner products. So:

\begin{align}
r(\alpha(v))(w) 
& = -w\\
\\
\alpha r (v)\alpha^{−1}(w) 
&= \alpha r (v)(\alpha^{−1}(w)) \\
&= \alpha (-\alpha^{−1}(w)) \\
&= -\alpha (\alpha^{−1}(w)) \\
&= -w
\end{align}

Thus the two sides agree both for vectors parallel and orthogonal to $v$, hence they agree everywhere.